# Is using jQuery a guarantee for cross browser compatibility?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser

I noticed that writing cross-browser compatible code in JavaScript could be a little difficult in some cases. Is using jQuery a guarantee that my JavaScript code works in all browsers?

Comment: [http://docs.jquery.com/Browser_compatibility](http://docs.jquery.com/Browser_compatibility)

Comment: It depends entirely on what you intend to do. For example, ajax requests are standardised within jQuery, so you can rest assured ajax will work across all browsers simply by coding it using jQuery. That is only one example.

Comment: Have a look at this page: http://docs.jquery.com/Browser_Compatibility

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can read on [jQuery's page about browser compatibility](http://docs.jquery.com/Browser_compatibility), it supports all modern browsers including old but widely used browsers like Internet Explorer 7. If you encounter an issue with a browser using jQuery, you should submit a bug report. The beauty with frameworks such as jQuery is their compatibility.

Good luck!

Answer (score 7):

jQuery provides good compatibility among modern browsers. There are, however, no guarantees. No one can offer you that.