# How do I read an XML file with jQuery in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

I want to read an XML file using jQuery. The example I am trying works in Chrome, but not in Firefox. Please help me to write the code, so it will work in Firefox.

**HTML code:**

```
<html>
<title> xml try</title>
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
        var markers = "";
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.get("File.xml", {}, function (xml){
              $('marker',xml).each(function(i){
                 markers = $(this).text();
                $('#data').html(''+markers);
                 document.write("hi "+markers);
                 document.write("");
              //alert('it is '+$(this));
              i++;
              });
            });
        });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="data"> div is </div>
    Hello
</body>
</html>
```

**XML code**:

```
<markers>
   <marker>
      <type>1</type>
      <title>1</title>
      <address>1</address>
      <latitude>1</latitude>
      <longitude>1</longitude>
   <marker>
   <marker>
      <type>2</type>
      <title>2</title>
      <address>2</address>
      <latitude>2</latitude>
      <longitude>2</longitude>
   <marker>
</markers>
```

Comment: As this(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6384707/is-using-jquery-a-guarantee-for-cross-browser-compatibility) question's accepted answer explains that jQuery is cross browser compatible it should work on all major browsers :)

Comment: check any errors in the console :)

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui  i don't get any error in console.

Comment: Whats the output of `xml` in firefox ? Some browsers wont allow you to read files stored locally when you run HTML file alone.

Comment: @2-Stroker in mozilla on windows it is not printing anything other than hello

Answer (score 2):

just replace your xml (you got errors with xml formatting) :

```
<markers>
   <marker>
     <type>1</type>
     <title>1</title>
     <address>1</address>
     <latitude>1</latitude>
     <longitude>1</longitude>
  </marker>
  <marker>
     <type>2</type>
     <title>2</title>
     <address>2</address>
     <latitude>2</latitude>
     <longitude>2</longitude>
  </marker>
</markers>
```

you need to close

```
<marker> </marker>
```

then it will work fine

Comment: but then how can chrome show his first implementation ?