# "js Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'zIndex' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, jquery

In order to change z-index of a picture after a action,I write the following code in js.

```
$("id").click(function{

     document.getElementsByClassName.style.zIndex = 2;
});
```

however,it show the error like

> js Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'zIndex' of undefined

is there anyone face the same problem and has solved it? THX

Comment: Mention the **class name** then iterate to apply. Eg:- `document.getElementsByClassName("some_class");` gives array of elements

Comment: The `.getElementsByClassName` method doesn't have a `style` property.

Comment: Yes, I forget to print it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First getElementsByClassName requires an argument passed to it, to specify which class name the elements should contain, you want to receive.

Just pick the first one of the returned array and operate on that value, be sure to check if the returned array contains any elements:

```
$("id").click(function{
 var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('some-class-name');
 if (elements.length > 0) {
  elements[0].style.zIndex = 2;
 }

});
```

But I really would suggest you to use jQuery to ensure cross browser compatibility.

```
$("id").click(function{
 var elements = $('.some-class-name');
 if (elements.length > 0) {
  elements.first().css({ 'z-index' : 2 });
 }

});
```

EDIT:
Because you said, you want to change the zIndex of ONE image object, I use first() in jQuery and [0] in vanilla JS to get operate on the first element, only. But just use an unique id attribute as identifier to query only one element in this case.

Comment: Hello,can you tell me why using jQuery can ensure cross broswer compatibility? THX

Comment: Check out [jQuery's current Browser for Desktop and mobile support](http://jquery.com/browser-support/) taken from [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6384707/is-using-jquery-a-guarantee-for-cross-browser-compatibility#6384757)

Answer (score 1):

**it can also be done with jquery**

```
$(".class_name").css("z-index","2");
```

Comment: Your answer may be right but you use **jQuery** which is not tagged in the question

Comment: But the Question code itself contains **jQuery**,that's why i answered

Comment: Added jQuery tag. Please add a bit more explanation to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

All you need is to provide a class name and iterate over elements:

```
$("id").click(function{
   var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("some_class");

   for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
      elems[i].style.zIndex = 2;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide arguments to `getElementsByClassName`. See the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName).

Answer (score 0):

You was missing parameter in function and elements are in array format if you use `getElementsByClassName` so you also need to specify elements position `[0]`, or do this in loop. Here is your running example.

```js
$("#test").click(function(){
document.getElementById("test").style.zIndex = 0;
document.getElementsByClassName("testClass")[0].style.zIndex = 999;
});

$(".testClass").click(function(){
document.getElementsByClassName("testClass")[0].style.zIndex = 0;  
document.getElementById("test").style.zIndex = 999;
});
```

```css
#test{
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-color:red;
  z-index:999;
  }

.testClass{
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-color:green;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test"> Test
  </div>

<div class="testClass">Test Class</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to me, as we know ID's in Javascript are unique to particular element but and in case of classes it is not. Classes are reuseable.

For to use class be specific which occurence of class your are going to use.

Below is my code which help me to resolve my issue.

```
funtion displayModal(){
     var play_button_overlay = document.getElementsByClassName("play_button")[0];
     play_button_overlay.style.zIndex="1";
    }
```